# Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using a virtual machine to do the work.

I given the volume capacity to be 32MB. According to "cat /proc/meminfo", i have approximately of 1.4GB for the memory available. It is more than enough to be mounted.

However, whenever it mounted, it will automatically unmounted as it cannot allocate memory (as seen on below pic). I tried to adjust the heap size but the result is still the same.

[Please take a look at the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5JPH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Assign more memory to the virtual machine even though it is already more than sufficient to hold the volume capacity